# Extra line drawn in Flotchart using TickRotor plugin

Tags: javascript, charts, flot, rotor

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart using FlotChart.
My challenge is to create a multiple x-axis labels up to 5 layers.
So, I tried to use TickRotor plugin (initially because I wanted to rotate the labels vertically).

Now, I wanted to draw some lines and tweaked some functions in TickRotor. However, a weird line is drawn somewhere in my chart. Could you please help me what's happening?

Here's the "else" part of the `plot.hooks.draw.push(function (plot, ctx)` :

```
if (ticks.length == 0) {
    return;
}
xaxis = plot.getAxes().xaxis;
var box = xaxis.box;
var tick, label, xoffset, yoffset;
var showWeek = false;
for (var i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++) {
    tick = ticks[i];
    if (!tick.label) {
        continue;
    }
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = font;
    if (rotateTicks <= 90) {
        // Center such that the top of the label is at the center of the tick.
        xoffset = -Math.ceil(Math.cos(radsAboveHoriz) * tick.height) - 10;
        yoffset = Math.ceil(Math.sin(radsAboveHoriz) * tick.height) - 10;
        ctx.translate(Math.round(plot.getPlotOffset().left + xaxis.p2c(tick.v)) + xoffset,
                      box.top + box.padding + plot.getOptions().grid.labelMargin + yoffset);
        ctx.rotate(rotateTicksRads);
    } else {
        // We want the text to facing up, so we have to
        // rotate counterclockwise, which means the label
        // has to *end* at the center of the tick.
        xoffset = Math.ceil(Math.cos(radsAboveHoriz) * tick.height)
                  - Math.ceil(Math.cos(radsAboveHoriz) * tick.width);
        yoffset = Math.ceil(Math.sin(radsAboveHoriz) * tick.width)
                  + Math.ceil(Math.sin(radsAboveHoriz) * tick.height);
        ctx.translate(Math.round(plot.getPlotOffset().left + xaxis.p2c(tick.v) + xoffset),
                      box.top + box.padding + plot.getOptions().grid.labelMargin + yoffset);
        ctx.rotate(-radsAboveHoriz);
    }
    var ticksMe = tick.label.split(" ");

    // draw labels
    ctx.fillText(ticksMe[0], 0, 0);
    if(showWeek){
        ctx.fillText(ticksMe[1], xoffset, yoffset * 2);
        showWeek = false;
    }
    else{
        showWeek = true;
        ctx.moveTo(-4,-10);
        ctx.lineTo(-4,(yoffset * 2));
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    ctx.restore();
}
```

Here's the image that show's where the weird line is drawn :
[image: Weird Line is Drawn Image]